# How do I get an image between to sections in css

Tags: html, css, z-index

I am working on a page and i got stuck. (Yes, I´m a beginner :-) .)

I have a Header followed by a section. I want to have  pictures that is between the header and section. I have positioned the image but it keeps going "under" the header so that you don't see half of it. I been trying to use z-index but i want work? My goal is to have half of the picture in the header-section and half if the other section.

Any tips? The beginning of my code is below (I omitted html, head for convenience).

```
<div class="big_mama">
    <header>
        <nav class="main_nav">
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header> 

    <section id="section">
        <article class="article">
            <div class="pictures">
                <img src="#" />
            </div>
       </article>
        <article class="article">
            <div class="pictures">
                <img src="#" />
            </div>
       </article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should place the image in header section. Set the header with the property `position:relative`, set `position:absolute` for the image you want to put and set `bottom:-50%` or `bottom:0px; margin-bottom:-50%`.

```
<header style="position:relative">
    <img src="#" style="position:absolute; bottom:-50%">
```

This should do the trick.

Cheers.

Comment: @ixxy83 It's ok. Mark it as answered.